# $f(x)\in \mathbb{R}$, $x\in D\cap\mathbb{R}$, implies $\overline{f(x)}= f(\overline{x})$, $x\in D$?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, complex-numbers

Let $f\colon D\to \mathbb{C}$, where $D\subseteq \mathbb{C}$, be such that $f(x)$ is real for all $x \in D\cap\mathbb{R}$. Let $\overline{a}$ denote the complex conjugate of $a\in\mathbb{C}$.

> **My question.** Does $f$ satisfy $\overline{f(x)}= f(\overline{x})$ for all $x\in D$? If not, under which conditions on $ f $ does this hold true?

Comment: What if $D$ is disjoint from the real line?  For something related, see the Schwarz reflection principle ... http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SchwarzReflectionPrinciple.html

Answer (score 0):

Of course not, since you can change any value of $f$ to let this equlity fail.

If $f(z)$ is entire, it holds. Let $g(z)=\overline{f(z)}-f(\bar{z})$, it's easy to verify that $g$ is entire.  However $g(x)=0$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$, which has limit points.  Therefore $g\equiv 0$.

Edit: Just as Chinnapparaj R said in the comment, since $D$ is open, $D\cap \mathbb R$ is also open and then the zero set of $g$ has a limit point.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo in the domain of $f$. I guess that now $f$ analytic in $D$ is sufficient for the equality to hold true.

Comment: $g $ is not zero for all $x \in \Bbb R$. Since $D\cap \Bbb R \neq \varnothing$, $D$ contains a non empty intervel of $\Bbb R$ and hence has a limit points. So by identity theorem, $g$ vanishes